# Magento 2 - preselect automatically customer billing address on checkout - when default is not set

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

When customer **has set default billing and shipping address** in his profile then on checkout shipping and billing address **is automatically checked** to default and **customer is able to place order.** In the case when customer **didnt set up default addresses in his profile** then customer needs to **select address on checkout and then click update.** After that he will be able to place order.

**How to programatically preselect first billing address in dropdown on checkout** so the customer does not need to do that, and to be able to click on place order without clicking update button?